# Symfony 2 Session headers already sent?

Tags: symfony

Im trying to start (or access) a session like so :

```
    $session = new Session();
    echo $session->getId();
```

Which according to the doc should be all i need because the session gets auto started (http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/sessions.html) :

```
While it is recommended to explicitly start a session, a sessions will actually start 
on demand, that is, if any session request is made to read/write session data.
```

Nevertheless, im getting the error

```
Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent.
```

Heres the original controller thats calling the service:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

        $auth = $this->get('authentication');
        $user_id = $auth->getUserId();
```

And then the getUserId function:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

public function getUserId() {
    $session = new Session();
    echo $session->getId();
```

And if i change the getUserId to look like this:

```
public function getUserId() {
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    echo $session->getId();
```

I get the error:

```
Call to a member function get() on a non-object
```

Comment: Have you sent any output to the browser before attempting to access the session?

Comment: @KevinM1 Not unless Symfony does by default

Comment: Where is this code in your code structure, in a Controller?

Comment: @AlexJoyce Yes in a controller being called by another controller

Comment: You should show exactly where in your controller you're attempting to create/access the session, and how/where the controller method is being called by the other controller.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at the documentation of the stand-alone component "HTTP Foundation". This means that you have to very careful about what applies when you use the full-stack framework symfony2.

Symfony2 already takes care of the Request/Response and the session, so you don't need to create any Session object. You can read about how to use the session in the normal documentation, Chapter [Controller](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/controller.html#managing-the-session).

To access a session in your controller, all you need is

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
```

If you want to access the session inside a service, you need to pass the service "Request" as a dependency in your service.yml and than access the session through

```
$session = $request->getSession();
```

If you are not used to it, the [Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) Chapter has some descriptions.

Comment: Interesting. When i implement it, it gives me the error `Fatal error:  Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /newsite/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php on line 180`

Comment: You are using the full-stack symfony2 framework? Are you using 2.0 or 2.1? Can you update the whole controller (inclusive class declaration/use statements)?

Comment: You can actually inject the `session` service when you need just the session and not the request. This way you avoid the [scoping problem](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html).

Comment: @Sgoettschkes 2.1, why should i have to update everything? I dont think theres any issues with my install..

Comment: Sorry, I meant if you cold update your post to show the controller.